# Fiding the test statistic, using wald test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, fisher-information, wald-test

Given the random sample $X_1,...,X_n \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, I want to perform a Wald test for:

$\mathrm{H}_\mathrm{0}: \mu = \mathrm{\mu}_\mathrm{0}$

$\mathrm{H}_\mathrm{1}: \mu \neq \mathrm{\mu}_\mathrm{0}$

What would be the test statistic here?

Generally, it is $T = |W| = (\hat{\theta} - \mathrm{\theta}_\mathrm{0})/ \hat{se}$

Is it simply $\hat{\mu}$ in this case? And in order to find what is it equal to, I need to find the MLE for $\mu$, correct? and that is by finding Fisher Information $I(\mu)$.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: the shortest answer I can think of is the $t$-test. For some results on the use of MLE see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/596430/56940) and for the $t$-test see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/595571/56940).

Comment: What do you mean by "and that is by finding Fisher Information $I(\mu)$." ?

Comment: Is $\sigma^2$ assumed to be known?